# adding values to objects in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to add the following to each object in a dictionary.
My dictionary looks like this:

```
{'Niveau1Obj1': {'Niveau2Obj1': {'Niveau3Obj1': {}}}}
```

For each object I want to add the following value:

```
{'type':'object'}
```

So the final outcome should look something like this:

```
{'Niveau1Obj1': {'type': 'object'}, 'Niveau2Obj1': {'type': 'object'}, 'Niveau3Obj1': {'type': 'object'}}
```

My code doesn't result in the desired outcome. The code is:

```
objects = {'Niveau1Obj1': {'Niveau2Obj1': {'Niveau3Obj1': {}}}}

for key, obj in objects.items():
    objects[key].setdefault(key, {}).update({'type':'object'})
```

It only adds the {'type':'object'} only to the last part of the dictionary.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a recursion:

```py
dct = {"Niveau1Obj1": {"Niveau2Obj1": {"Niveau3Obj1": {}}}}


def get_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            yield k
            yield from get_keys(d[k])


out = {k: {"type": "object"} for k in get_keys(dct)}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Niveau1Obj1": {"type": "object"},
    "Niveau2Obj1": {"type": "object"},
    "Niveau3Obj1": {"type": "object"},
}
```